# How to change current time in audio playback?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I am trying to play an audio file with an offset of 10 seconds into the recording:

```
const audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');
audio.currentTime = 10
console.log('currentTime: ' + audio.currentTime)
console.log('duration: ' + audio.duration)
audio.play();
```

The output:

```
curretTime: 10
duration: NaN
```

Now this code will play the audio - but it will start from the beginning.
How do I start the playback 10 seconds into the audio?
Also, why is the duration printing as "NaN" ?

Comment: You don't want to know about why the `.duration` is `NaN`? It needs a delay so the metadata is fully loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing "n" from currentTime.
should be audio.currentTime = 10;